# CSS div is not floating next to image

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to make responsive design. When screen is small comments should be below "Slikica"(Cyan DIV). But when I'm on the desktop version I want comments (Gray divs) to be warped around image.

- Cyan div has fixed width, and float left.
- Gray divs has unknown length (max 200chars), and they should be right to Cyan div. They are also floated left.
- If I set them width, 300px for example everything will work fine.

Look at image below, worth thousand of words.

[image: Showing problem]

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="slikica">Slikica</div>
    <div class="gray">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec elementum dui ut enim rutrum congue. Nulla ut odio vel metus pharetra aliquet. Proin nec erat non nisl semper sagittis. Pellentesque sed.</div>
    <div class="gray">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris imperdiet interdum enim eget sollicitudin. Praesent eleifend interdum odio sit amet luctus. Nulla egestas eros vitae dui tincidunt amet.</div>
    <div class="gray">Quisque non ligula id dolor tincidunt imperdiet at et libero. Cras eu sapien mi. Phasellus sollicitudin accumsan vehicula. In fermentum, sapien vitae ullamcorper porttitor, felis sem dapibus est amet.</div>
    <div class="gray">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec elementum dui ut enim rutrum congue. Nulla ut odio vel metus pharetra aliquet. Proin nec erat non nisl semper sagittis. Pellentesque sed.</div>
    <div class="gray">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris imperdiet interdum enim eget sollicitudin. Praesent eleifend interdum odio sit amet luctus. Nulla egestas eros vitae dui tincidunt amet.</div>
    <div class="gray">Quisque non ligula id dolor tincidunt imperdiet at et libero. Cras eu sapien mi. Phasellus sollicitudin accumsan vehicula. In fermentum, sapien vitae ullamcorper porttitor, felis sem dapibus est amet.</div>
    <br class="clrfix" />
</div>
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/PTq23/1/)

Comment: Can you prepare a jsFiddle and post link here?

Comment: Post the CSS code as well. To be more clear

Comment: @rt2800 http://jsfiddle.net/PTq23/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `float: left;` on the comment DIVs. When floating each comment left to previous one, they won't fit into the viewport.

http://jsfiddle.net/feeela/Xtuc9/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following CSS to the comments' `div` element:

```css
display:inline;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `float: left;` from your gray divs and add a left margin equal to (or larger) than the cyan div width they will occupy the space to the right. If there are more gray divs they will however not wrap around the cyan div because of the margin. I don't know if this behavior is wanted. Otherwise you could just skip both the margin and the floating and have them wrap around the cyan div.

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your divs will expand to reach at maximum the width of their container (in that case, the `<div id="content">`). When they reach a width too big to fit aside the blue, they get clip down. What you need is to put something that prevent them from reaching that width.

You have two option to do this.

1. Put a div with a `width: 600px` (or whatever fit in that space) and put every gray div in it. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PTq23/3/) (You'll need to expand the result window to see that it work)
2. Put a `max-width` on every div (example: `max-width: 600px`)

Comment: But then it's weird, divs that are below Cyan one are too small, I want them stretched.

Comment: Then you'll need to expand the page width, you can't really stretched the gray div without going out of the limit that their container sets.